# Cookiecutter Django on docker-compose stops hot reloading

Tags: docker-compose, hot-reload, cookiecutter-django

At random points in development, hot reload stops working on a Cookiecutter Django application. It happened to me 3 times in different projects, at seemingly random points. There's been no changes to the initial `Dockerfile` and `local.yml` script that is used to launch the application. I have tried rebooting docker engine and pruning the entire system but it doesn't affect the problem. What might I be missing?

Comment: Are you on Mac?

Comment: I primarily work on Linux but I have also tested this on Windows. It's not an OS-related issue.